# How to make a continuous vertical line in vim?

Tags: vim, line

I want to make a table in vim.

Making a horizontal line is easy

```
______________________________
```

For the vertical I use this

```
yes "|" | head -10
```

But the result is bad

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

I want something contiguous like the horizontal line. How can I do this?

Comment: Might interest you to know [vi.se] is available!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your version of Vim is compiled with `multibyte` support and your terminal encoding is set correctly, you may use the Unicode [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character), which include horizontal and vertical lines as well as several varieties of intersections and blocks. Vim defines some default digraphs for these characters, such as `vv` for `│` (to enter a digraph, you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>; thus in insert mode `^Kvv` will insert the character `│` at the cursor location). For the full list if your version of Vim supports it, type `:digraphs`; for more information on the feature and to search by Unicode character name, type `:help digraphs`.

Depending on your terminal settings and choice of font, however, box-drawing characters may not all render as connected lines, so your mileage may vary. For instance, on my machine vertical lines render as connected in the terminal (using Source Code Pro), but as broken lines in GVim (using DejaVu Sans Mono):

[image: Box-drawing characters rendering as solid lines in the terminal]
[image: Box-drawing characters rendered as broken lines in GVim]

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, regarding the previous answer:

- `^kvv` leads to │
- `^kdr` leads to ┌
- `^khh` leads to ─
- `^kdl` leads to ┐
- `^kur` leads to └
- `^kul` leads to ┘

Notice you can use upper case for a thicker line:

- `^kVV` is ┃
- `^kDR` is ┏
- `^kHH` is ━
- `^kLD` is ┓ (LD, and not DL, for some reason)
- `^kUR` is ┗
- `^kUL` is ┛

There are also versions with one upper and one lower case.